# Plotting a Histogram in D3 without knowing number of bins

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a function that creates a histogram for a given array. Clearly, there's no data for the X-Axis and I have to choose the bins arbitrarily. What would be the best way to do so?

My code:

```
var width = 700, height = 500, pad = 30, barPadding = 1;

        function plotHistogram(element, dataset) {

            var svg = d3.select(element)
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height)

            var bars = svg.append("g")


            // Container box
            var rectangle = svg.append("rect")
                            .attr("height", height)
                            .attr("width", width)
                            .attr("stroke-width", 2).attr("stroke", "#ccc")
                            .attr("fill", "transparent")

            var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                    // Using default domain (0 - 1)
                    .range([pad, width - pad * 2])

            var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d; })])
                            .range([height - pad, pad])

            var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
            var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - pad) + ")")
                .call(xAxis)

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + pad +", 0)")
                .call(yAxis)

            svg.selectAll("bars")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                    .append("rect")

                    // Evenly spacing out bars
                    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * width/dataset.length; })

                    // Top of each bar as the top of svg. To remove inverted bar graph.
                    .attr("y", function(d) { return height - (d * 4); })

                    // To give padding between bars
                    .attr("width", width / dataset.length - barPadding)

                    // To make the bars taller
                    .attr("height", function(d) { return d * 4; })
                    .attr("fill", "teal");


        }
        // #normal is the id of the div element.
        plotHistogram("#normal", [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]);
```

---

**Edit 1:** I have decided to use the default bin size (0 - 1) for the xScale above. I'm facing problems creating the bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate the bins as in https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450

The array in your `plotHistogram` is like the array `data` in @mbostock's bl.ock...

HTH